# Is it possible to pass an "unnamed" variable to a function?

Tags: c++

Let's say there is the following function:

```
void SetTheSize(const SIZE *size) { ... }
```

Is there any way to call that function without specifying the SIZE variable? e.g.,

```
SetTheSize((const SIZE*)&{10, 10});
```

**edit:**
I should had mentioned that the SIZE is a struct, without SIZE(int, int) constructor.

Comment: Since variables are basically named objects in C++, an anonymous variable is simply an object :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, only thing nearest in C++ is to do like this:

```
void SetTheSize(const SIZE& size); //Change the pointer to const reference
```

And call it using an unnamed temporary variable: `SetTheSize(SIZE(10,10));`

Comment: Thanks Naveen, I guess your solution will neither work and that's my fault (sorry about that). I've edited the question.

Comment: @Tassos: In that case I don't see any possibility of doing this using unnamed variables.

Answer (score 1):

`SetTheSize(&SIZE{10, 10});` would "work" with the improved initialization syntax in C++0x.

It "only" deserves a warning: taking address of a temporary.

Legal things to do would be to bind the temporary to references:

```
void SetTheSize(SIZE&&);
```

or

```
void SetTheSize(const Size&);
```

with usage

```
SetTheSize(Size{10, 10});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it via a pointer, although you can pass a temporary via a const reference. And you can't create arrays like that (if that's what your syntax is trying to do). So, no.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers so far have been pedantic, and somebody's got to do it.  It's actually really quite easy:

```
void SetTheSize(const SIZE *size);
SIZE const newSize(10, 10);
SetTheSize(&newSize);
```

The variable being passed to `SetTheSize` is indeed an unnamed temporary.  It is the result of the expression `&newSize` and has type `SIZE const*`.

If you wanted the `SIZE` object itself to be an unnamed temporary, instead of the pointer passed to `SetTheSize`, that's possible too:

```
void SetTheSize(const SIZE *size);
SIZE const& newSize = SIZE(10, 10);
SetTheSize(&newSize);
```

Now `newSize` is a reference to an unnamed temporary variable.